# Error installing libgfortran3 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, compiler, fortran, conda

I'm working on a project where I have to compile the code from another author. He uses very old packages so I'm traying to recreate the enviroment on conda, but I cannot find any good repo for Ubuntu 20.04 that contain the library libgfortran3 and it is one of the most importante one on the code. When I tried to compile with libgfortran 4 I got this error

```
/home/jenekew/anaconda3/envs/fortran/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libgfortran.so.3, needed by /home/jenekew/anaconda3/envs/fortran/lib/liblapack.so, may conflict with libgfortran.so.4
```

Everything can help me!

Comment: In my opinion this is not an error, just a warning.

Comment: If you'd like us to troubleshoot the code, you'll need to provide the code.  If your question has more to do with software development than using Ubuntu, you might consider posting this question on StackOverflow.